# Which community is better for machine learning questions?

Tags: discussion, machine-learning, datascience-stackexchange

I have asked a question on this community prior to this question. It was well-answered, and I adore this community. However, I have a question. It appears to be centered around statistics, but I also noticed that it is open to questions on machine learning, and that there are a lot of questions in that category.

However, I have recently seen a community called "[Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)" that also appears specific to my task, even having a more computer-centric approach, with a focus on machine learning as well.

Which communities are better to post questions on machine learning?

Comment: You might find answers to this question at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2253.  It would be wise to [look at the site statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/55053?phase=beta), too, if you care whether your question survives as a useful resource for future readers. Regardless of the site, it's important to do some research before asking any question, which is a little harder here because we probably already have the answer somewhere!